# Optimizing Mercurial repository size

Tags: mercurial

How does one optimize Mercurial repositories so that older revisions take the minimum required space?

I am aware that Mercurial does some magic already to group and compress existing commits. However, is there a way to enforce a manual run of this operation, so that as much space as possible is saved, disregarding speed? Is it possible to pack as many repos in one stream, change compression algorithm -- anything to better compress old changesets?

I don't have a lot of large-sized repositories right now, but I do have some medium-to-big sized ones that could use some shrinkage in the early history.

---

Git appears to have `git gc [--aggressive]` which, to a git non-expert, seems to do some magic cutting down the cruft and compressing the repos. It also has `git repack` which [also seems](http://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/) to be doing the same thing, albeit with some additional expert options. At least that's how it seems to me: change sets can be 'packed' differently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [shrink-revlog.py](https://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/src/tip/contrib/shrink-revlog.py) extension in the mercurial/contrib directory? On very branchy repositories it may cut down the size of the manifest significantly (OTOH, it had zero effect for me on a nearly 1GB manifest in a repo converted from subversion).

Comment: We have a very branchy repository. However, shrink doesn't seem to work at all. I mean, after "shrinking" the size is still the same. If I do a series of hg convert statements, optimizing the order by hand on my small test repo I get way better results.